# Add content from within another content type in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm pretty new to Drupal and I can't figure out how to do the following:

In Drupal 7, I have a custom content type called 'Opening' and I want users to be able to apply to an opening. 
So I created another content type ('Application') and I'd like the Opening content type to have a static field of some sort (ideally a button but could live with a basic link for now) that creates a new Application content (i.e. points to mysite/node/add/application). Besides, the Application should be somehow prepopulated with the Opening it "came from" (hope this makes sense).

I thought this would be straightforward but I've been searching around and I couldn't find a way to implement this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the [workflow](http://drupal.org/project/workflow) module.

That module seems like it has the functionality that your looking for.  In that, you can create steps that users/multiple users must take to process information. In your case, you may want to make just one content type (say, Opening), and make the steps via workflow to match the cycle you need.

Additionally, if you looking to just make a form, you could use the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module to create the application form.  You could specify that users who have filled out the form are granted permissions to use the opening content type.

Good Luck!

Comment: Great! I'll try that and update this thread to let others know. Thanks for your help!